# App crashed in Android version 5.0 and above

Tags: android, sdk, build-tools

I develop the Android App but there is problem i'm facing that my App run proper in all versions except the 5.0 and above. I was searching the solution from many days but still not get the answer, i have applied many methods

gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vs.vertosys"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter() {}

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    compile 'com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:+'
}
```

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vs.vertosys" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.vs.vertosys.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.vs.vertosys.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".PushActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DesignActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".FragmentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"/>


        <meta-data android:name="PW_APPID" android:value="BAA2E-9B159" />
        <meta-data android:name="PW_PROJECT_ID" android:value="A610486581713" />


        <activity android:name="com.pushwoosh.richpages.RichPageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.pushwoosh.MessageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.pushwoosh.PushHandlerActivity" />



        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.vs.vertosys" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.pushwoosh.GCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.pushwoosh.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.pushwoosh.GCMRegistrationService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.pushwoosh.local.AlarmReceiver" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log cat:

```
03-01 16:09:25.073 705-774/? E/Sensors: new acc setDelay handle(7),ns(200000000) err! go to hwmsen
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote: Zygote:  error closing descriptor
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:221)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:715)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
03-01 16:09:33.625 20238-20238/? E/Zygote:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 16:09:33.982 20238-20238/? E/kris: false
03-01 16:09:33.982 20238-20238/? E/kris: true
03-01 16:09:33.983 20238-20238/? E/kris11111: false
03-01 16:09:33.986 20238-20238/? E/kris2222: false
03-01 16:09:33.989 20238-20238/? E/kris2222: false
03-01 16:09:34.137 20238-20238/? E/ffi_jank: timespan = 44.640076
03-01 16:09:35.648 705-715/? E/Sensors: new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(1000000) err! go to hwmsen
03-01 16:09:36.097 705-767/? E/Sensors: new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(1000000) err! go to hwmsen
03-01 16:09:39.056 794-794/? E/ffi_jank: timespan = 23.815077
03-01 16:10:00.034 944-944/? E/MyTag: updateClock : 4:10
03-01 16:10:00.068 944-944/? E/MyTag: updateClock : 4:10 PM
03-01 16:10:00.093 944-944/? E/MyTag: updateClock : 4:10 PM
03-01 16:10:00.134 1232-1232/? E/ActionIcon: time changed: time = 20160301T161000Asia/Calcutta(2,60,19800,0,1456828800)
03-01 16:10:00.147 20238-20238/? E/kris2222: false
03-01 16:10:00.153 794-794/? E/ffi_jank: timespan = 83.53192
03-01 16:10:00.203 794-794/? E/ffi_jank: timespan = 24.309769
03-01 16:10:00.216 20238-20238/? E/ffi_jank: timespan = 43.211075
```

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar in a log cat there is no any shows error.

Comment: you ask in question app crash and log cat not show error. i can't understand that. post log cat that through get solution.

Comment: Connect your device to your computer, run the app from android studio, look at the device monitor for logcat ouput, then copy paste whatever comes in red right when your app crashes, without any direction we can't help you

Comment: @Gurpreet " in logcat there are no error logs" - hard to believe, there are may be Verbose warnings or something. Where your app is crushing? On Start, On some Button click?

Comment: @VladimirKulyk might be possible if he still has to enable logging on his phone. I know I had to.

Comment: @Bhargav actually i have 4.4.2 version device so i know when i connected 5.0 version then its show the error moreover i also try genymotion but problem is its not install in my system..

Comment: this log cat when i connect the 4.4.2 device